Is there a way for this to sort into a rectangle? Also, how would one compute this mathematically?

Is there a rigorous way to solve a problem like this. Also is there a solution to this exact case?

See a rectangular arrangement with hole in the Wikipedia article about tetrominoes here

Hint:
Imagine the playing-space to be grid-like and colored like a checkerboard with every other square being black vs white.
If you were to successfully make a rectangle, what shapes are possible in terms of lengths of sides?  How many black squares must be used?  How many white?

 How many black squares are in each of your pieces?  How many white?

$~$

 Look at the T piece more closely.

